# How to pass a class method to SetWindowLongPtr()?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I want to handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages in a `TComboBox` drop-down list, to show item-aware hints.  But I just can't make `SetWindowLongPtr()` work.

If I don't use a functional type variable (`TWndProc`), the compiler stops with "Not enough parameter" / "Variable required" errors.

If I pass the variable's address (`@ptrWndProc`), it compiles, but instantly crashes on drop-down.

I tried to make `prtWndProc` a global variable, but the crash does not disappear.

Could somebody make it work?

Method pointer `TWndProc` type solution:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  PWndProc = ^TWndProc;
  TWndProc = function (hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT of object; stdcall;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fDropDownListHandle : THandle;
    fOldDropDownWndProc : TWndProc;
  protected
    function SubClassProc(hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
  public
    { Public declarations }

  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation


{$R *.dfm}

function TForm3.SubClassProc(hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
begin
  case ( msg ) of
    WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      ;
    else
      result := fOldDropDownWndProc( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
var
  ptrWndProc : TWndProc;
begin
  ptrWndProc := SubClassProc;
  fOldDropDownWndProc := PWndProc( SetWindowLongPtr( ComboBox1.Handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR( @ptrWndProc ) ) )^;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetWindowLongPtr( ComboBox1.Handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR( @fOldDropDownWndProc ) );
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  cbi : TCOMBOBOXINFO;
begin
  GETCOMBOBOXINFO( ComboBox1.Handle, cbi );
  fDropDownListHandle := cbi.hwndList;
end;

end.
```

Regular function `TWndProc` type solution:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  PWndProc = ^TWndProc;
  TWndProc = function (hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fDropDownListHandle : THandle;
  public
    { Public declarations }

  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation


{$R *.dfm}

var
  GLOBAL_ptrWndProc : TWndProc;
  GLOBAL_OldDropDownWndProc : TWndProc;

function SubClassProc(hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  case ( msg ) of
    WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      ;
    else
      result := GLOBAL_OldDropDownWndProc( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GLOBAL_ptrWndProc := SubClassProc;
  GLOBAL_OldDropDownWndProc := PWndProc( SetWindowLongPtr( ComboBox1.Handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR( @GLOBAL_ptrWndProc ) ) )^;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetWindowLongPtr( ComboBox1.Handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR( @GLOBAL_OldDropDownWndProc ) );
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  cbi : TCOMBOBOXINFO;
begin
  GETCOMBOBOXINFO( ComboBox1.Handle, cbi );
  fDropDownListHandle := cbi.hwndList;
end;

end.
```

The DFM:

```
object Form3: TForm3
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form3'
  ClientHeight = 411
  ClientWidth = 852
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ComboBox1: TComboBox
    Left = 192
    Top = 96
    Width = 145
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'ComboBox1'
    OnCloseUp = ComboBox1CloseUp
    OnDropDown = ComboBox1DropDown
  end
end
```

Comment: Your `TForm3.SubClassProc` is a *[method](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Methods_(Delphi))*. It has a hidden `Self` parameter, which you certainly don't want here!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I modified the source. Solution 1/2. Method pointer and regular procedural type. But the instant GPF is the same.

Comment: See [Subclassing Controls Using ComCtl32.dll version 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview#subclassing-controls-using-comctl32dll-version-6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you are hooking the `TComboBox`'s own `HWND`, not the `HWND` of its drop-down list.  The VCL already hooks the `TComboBox`'s `HWND` for you, so to process messages sent directly to the `TComboBox` itself, you can simply:

- derive a new class from `TComboBox` and override the virtual [`WndProc()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc) method, or use a [`message` handler](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Message_Methods).
- to hook an existing object (as in your example), just subclass its public [`WindowProc`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.WindowProc) property.

Either way, no need to deal with `SetWindowLongPtr()` at all.

Now, since you actually want to hook the drop-down list instead (otherwise why are you retrieving its `HWND`?), then you cannot use a **non-static class method** as a Win32 callback (at least, not the way you are trying to).  It has a hidden `Self` parameter which the API won't be able to pass back in when calling your callback.

Also, you are passing the wrong memory addresses to `SetWindowLongPtr()`, which is why you are crashing.  You are passing in the addresses of variables, not the addresses of functions.

Also, when using `SetWindowLongPtr()` to subclass an `HWND`, you can't call the old window procedure *directly*, you must use [`CallWindowProc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-callwindowprocw) instead.

That being said, you have 3 alternatives to make your code work:

- use a **`static` class method** (or a standalone function) with `SetWindowLongPtr()`.  If you need to access the `TComboBox` from inside your callback, you can store the `TComboBox` object pointer in the drop-down list's `HWND`:

```pascal
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fDropDownListHandle : HWND;
    fOldDropDownWndProc : TFNWndProc;
  protected
    class function SubClassProc(hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall; static;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

class function TForm3.SubClassProc(hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  cb: TComboBox;
begin
  case ( msg ) of
    WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      begin
        cb := TComboBox( GetProp( fDropDownListHandle, 'ComboBoxPtr' ) );
        // use cb as needed ...
      end;
    else
      Result := CallWindowProc( fOldDropDownWndProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if fDropDownListHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    SetWindowLongPtr( fDropDownListHandle, GWLP_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR( fOldDropDownWndProc ) );
    RemoveProp( fDropDownListHandle, 'ComboBoxPtr' );
    fDropDownListHandle := 0;
    fOldDropDownWndProc := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
var
  cbi : TCOMBOBOXINFO;
begin
  cbi.cbSize := SizeOf(cbi);
  if GetComboBoxInfo( ComboBox1.Handle, cbi ) and ( cbi.hwndList <> 0 ) then
  begin
    fDropDownListHandle := cbi.hwndList;
    SetProp( fDropDownListHandle, 'ComboBoxPtr', THandle( ComboBox1 ) );
    fOldDropDownWndProc := TFNWndProc( SetWindowLongPtr( fDropDownListHandle, GWLP_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR( @SubClassProc ) ) );
  end;
end;

end.
```

- use a **`static` class method** (or a standalone function) with [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass), which allows you to pass around a user-defined value, such as the `TComboBox` object pointer. No need to store it in the subclassed `HWND` itself:

```pascal
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.CommCtrl, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fDropDownListHandle : HWND;
  protected
    class function SubClassProc(hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM; uIdSubclass: UINT_PTR; dwRefData: DWORD_PTR): LRESULT; stdcall; static;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

class function TForm3.SubClassProc(hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM; uIdSubclass: UINT_PTR; dwRefData: DWORD_PTR): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  cb: TComboBox;
begin
  case ( msg ) of
    WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      begin
        cb := TComboBox( dwRefData );
        // use cb as needed ...
      end;
    else
      Result := DefSubclassProc( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if fDropDownListHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    RemoveWindowSubclass( fDropDownListHandle, @SubClassProc, 1 );
    fDropDownListHandle := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
var
  cbi : TCOMBOBOXINFO;
begin
  cbi.cbSize := SizeOf(cbi);
  if GetComboBoxInfo( ComboBox1.Handle, cbi ) and ( cbi.hwndList <> 0 ) then
  begin
    fDropDownListHandle := cbi.hwndList;
    SetWindowSubclass( fDropDownListHandle, @SubClassProc, 1, DWORD_PTR( ComboBox1 ) );
  end;
end;

end.
```

- use the RTL's [`MakeObjectInstance()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.MakeObjectInstance) function to create a *proxy stub* so that you can use a **non-`static` class method** with `SetWindowLongPtr()` (does not work with `SetWindowSubclass()`):

```pascal
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fDropDownListHandle : HWND;
    fOldDropDownWndProc : TFNWndProc;
    fNewDropDownWndProc: Pointer;
  protected
    procedure SubClassProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fNewDropDownWndProc := MakeObjectInstance( SubClassProc );
end;

procedure TForm3.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeObjectInstance( fNewDropDownWndProc );
end;

procedure TForm3.SubClassProc(var TMessage: TMessage);
begin
  case ( Message.Msg ) of
    WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      begin
        // use ComboBox1 as needed ...
      end;
    else
      Message.Result := CallWindowProc( fOldDropDownWndProc, fDropDownListHandle, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam );
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if fDropDownListHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    SetWindowLongPtr( fDropDownListHandle, GWLP_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR( fOldDropDownWndProc ) );
    fDropDownListHandle := 0;
    fOldDropDownWndProc := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
var
  cbi : TCOMBOBOXINFO;
begin
  cbi.cbSize := SizeOf(cbi);
  if GetComboBoxInfo( ComboBox1.Handle, cbi ) and ( cbi.hwndList <> 0 ) then
  begin
    fDropDownListHandle := cbi.hwndList;
    fOldDropDownWndProc := TFNWndProc( SetWindowLongPtr( fDropDownListHandle, GWLP_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR( fNewDropDownWndProc ) ) );
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: The VCL controls has a ShowHint property, but how can I show/hide the hint window for a Windows control? (fDropDownListHandle) I set ComboBox1.Hint and ShowHint but does not appear any HintWindow.

Comment: @SOLIDDeveloper of course not, because the drop down list is not hooked into, or tracked by, the VCL, so it has no concept of what you are trying to accomplish with it. You will likely have to show hide your own hint window manually. Or maybe you can use `Application.ActivateHint()`/`Application.CancelHint()`

Comment: I used CancelHint and ActivateHint, around the hint prop modification yet. But when the list droppeddown, the hintwindow of the combobox is not visible. When I idle over the dropdown list, the hint window of the combobox wont appear.

Comment: @SOLIDDeveloper then you will just have to show your own hint window manually.